# Reduce a list with entries made up of Bool and Rational values in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell

I got a list that contains entries which are made up of a Bool and a Rational value that looks like this:

```
[(False,1 % 40),(False,9 % 40),(False,1 % 40),(False,9 % 40),  
 (False,1 % 40),(False,9 % 40),(False,1 % 40),(True,9 % 40)]
```

I want to reduce the entries that share a Bool value into one and also add up the corresponding Rational values.

The result for the above example should look like this:

```
[(False,31 % 40),(True,9 % 40)]
```

I am new to Haskell and tried to accomplish the task using foldM, but I don't think that's the right way to do it.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What if there are no tuples with `True` and/or `False`, is the result then `0 % 1`?

Comment: can you show what you have tried with `foldM` and  where you are stuck?

Comment: Use `partition` from `Data.List`, after that you can do the summing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think with `foldM` you are already going in the right direction - although the `M` is not necessary as your function can be implemented purely - i.e. without side effects.

I would use a `Map Bool Rational` (from the containers package) for the accumulator - as this can be generalized easily if your tuples have a more complex type in the first position.

```
import qualified Data.Map as M

processList :: (Ord k, Bounded k, Enum k, Num v) => [(k,v)] -> [(k,v)]
processList = M.toList . foldr' (uncurry (M.insertWith (+))) init
  where init = M.fromList [(x,0) | x <- [minBound..maxBound] ]
```

alternatively you can use

```
  where init = M.empty
```

if you don't want default values (`0%1`) in the list, then you can also drop the `Enum` and `Bounded` constraints

Comment: Well gosh as long as you're using `Data.Map` might as well make it easy on yourself `M.toList . M.fromListWith (+)`

Comment: Totally forgot about `fromListWith`

Comment: I chose this as best answer as it was the easiest to understand for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can indeed use a `fold` here. I would here use a 2-tuple where for example the first element contains the sum of the `False`s, and the second the sum of the `True`s:

```
import Control.Arrow(first, second)
import Data.Bool(bool)

dsum :: (Foldable f, Num a) => f (Bool, a) -> (a, a)
dsum = foldr (uncurry ((. (+)) . bool first second)) (0,0)
```

For a foldable of `(Bool, a)` tuples, it will thus calculate a 2-tuple where the first element contains the sum of the `(False, ...)` tuples, and the second the sum of the `(True, ...)` tuples.

Here the `(uncurry ((. (+)) . bool first second))` is a compact representation of a function `f`:

```
f :: Num a => (Bool, a) -> (a, a) -> (a, a)
f (False, d) (a, b) = (d+a, b)
f (True, d) (a, b) = (a, d+b)
```

For example:

```
Prelude> d = [(False,1 % 40),(False,9 % 40),(False,1 % 40),(False,9 % 40), (False,1 % 40),(False,9 % 40),(False,1 % 40),(True,9 % 40)]
Prelude> dsum d
(31 % 40,9 % 40)
```

By using a 2-tuple, we thus add a "contract" that we will have *exactly* two elements, which is usually preferrable over a list that will always contain two items.

Answer (score 1):

I think the solution below is more appropriate for beginners but it won't work if your list has no tuples with either True or False (you can solve this easily. Give it a try ;) )

```
sumBooleans :: (Num a) => [(Bool,a)] -> [(Bool,a)]
sumBooleans l = map (foldr1 sumTuples) grouppedList
   where sumTuples (b,r) (_, r') = (b, r + r')
         grouppedList = groupBy myCondition l
         myCondition (b,_) (b', _) = b == b'
```

So `grouppedList` is a list containing two list. One list is all "True tuples", and the other is all "False tuples". Then you reduce each list using `foldr1 sumTuples` (you have to map this `foldr1 sumTuples` because you have a list of lists).

Have you considered that a list is not the best data structure for the output of your function?

Best,

Comment: Beware that this does not work well if `False`s and `True`s alternate in the input list.